# numpy.where condition to select specific vertical columns in 2D array

Tags: python, arrays, numpy

say we have

```
a = numpy.arange(25).reshape(5,5)

> array([[ 0,  1,  2,  3,  4],
         [ 5,  6,  7,  8,  9],
         [10, 11, 12, 13, 14],
         [15, 16, 17, 18, 19],
         [20, 21, 22, 23, 24]])
```

By going

```
numpy.where(a[1])

> array([0, 1, 2, 3, 4])
```

and then something like

```
a[1][numpy.where(a[1])]

> array([5, 6, 7, 8, 9])
```

I can select the horizontal rows of an array and the respective values, However how can I have a similar where condition to select only specific vertical columns

ie.

```
numpy.where(condition)

> array([1, 6, 11, 16, 21])
```

Answer (score 1):

I'm not sure exactly if this is what you mean, but you can index columns using `[:,column_number]`, where `:` stands for "all rows":

```
a[:,1][numpy.where(a[1])]

# array([ 1,  6, 11, 16, 21])
```

The above, however, is equivalent to simply `a[:,1]`:

```
>>> a[:,1]
array([ 1,  6, 11, 16, 21])
```

Comment: perfect thanks, although whats does the comma `,` stand for?

Comment: Thats how you separate the "row" index and the "column" index. So `[2,3]` would select row `2`, column `3`

Answer (score 1):

Have a look at this tutorial to learn how to apply slicing on numpy arrays (https://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy-1.15.1/reference/arrays.indexing.html). As for your question, the answer is:

```
a[:,1]
```